# Is "Science Fiction & Fantasy" a subset of "Movies & TV"?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-evaluation

Just trying to understand, would it be correct to say that the [Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) site is a subset of the [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site on stackexchange? Would an in-topic question asked on both sites earn the same kind of answers? If so, why are there two sites?

It is difficult to know which is a suitable place to get answers for a particular question related to a Science Fiction / Fantasy movie, how does one choose where to post the question given cross posting is not an option?

Comment: Related: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2/49.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Science Fiction and Fantasy covers all forms of media, not just Movies and TV shows. This includes books, comics, websites, etc.

Movies and TV only covers... Movies and TV.

Comment: Ah, I see. There seems to be a lot of overlap however, it is difficult to know which is a suitable place to get answers for a particular question related to a Science Fiction / Fantasy movie, how does one choose where to post the question given cross posting is not an option?

Comment: Generally, whichever site you want to ask it on. Only ask on one though, cross posting isn't allowed. The same cross over occurs for anime & manga when discussing animes.

Comment: @Tivep Just use the place you feel most comfortable in. If you feel comfortable in both places, it comes down if you're more interested in the overall in-universe perspective or more into the movie-side perspective. While I don't say that one of those questions would be off-topic on the other site, it may be used as a guidance. For example the SciFi people are way more engaged in coming up with all kinds of weird in-universe explanations based on various different sources and not just the movie itself. Such an answer wouldn't be bad here either, but it may be more likely there.

Comment: @Tivep For more information: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/376/49.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, ah I see. Does makes sense now that you mention in-universe vs in-movie.